# Javascript: Convert a JSON string into ES6 map or other to preserve the order of keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

**Is there a native (built in) in ES6 (or subsequent versions), Javascript or in TypeScript method to convert a JSON string to ES6 map OR a self-made parser to be implemented is the option?** The goal is to preserve the order of the keys of the JSON string-encoded object.

**Note:** I deliberately don't use the word "parse" to avoid converting a JSON string first to ECMA script / JavaScript object which by definition has no order of its keys.

For example:

```
{"b": "bar", "a": "foo" }        // <-- This is how the JSON string looks
```

I need:

```
{ b: "bar", a: "foo" }           // <-- desired (map version of it)
```

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"b": "bar", "a": "foo" }')` results in `{b: "bar", a: "foo"}` for me, order seems to be kept. (it's *numeric* properties you have to worry about). For non-numeric keys, IIRC order *is* preserved when you iterate over the keys *in ES6+* or something like that (but not in ES5)

Comment: You want object and do not want to convert string to object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are right about JSON.parse(), I removed it from the description. The idea is that what I see in Chrome console Network tab, sub-tab Preview is the string in order I expect, but in the Angular HttpClient get, the object that I receive after transformed via key-value pipe and render it in *ngFor loop the order is alphabetical, so I need a transformation to a map or array to fix the order of the keys. Can you suggest an approach ?

Comment: Objects properties do not have a set order! They may do when in JSON but once transformed to JS, the order is implementation dependent. Any iteration just guarantees you will get *consistent* ordering, as in, the order will be the same between two different iterations, not that you can set how the keys show up.

Comment: @vlaz, did you read the note to my question ?

Comment: I can't stress enough how bad of an idea this is. The whole point of JSON is that it's a consistent interchange format. The JSON specification does not require preserving the order of properties, so relying on property order is a recipe for problems. If order matters, you shouldn't use an object.

Comment: @zaggi yes and what you call a "map" is a JavaScript object. Said object does NOT have a guaranteed order to its properties.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

https://jsbin.com/kiqeneluzi/1/edit?js,console

The only thing that I do differently is to get the keys with regex to maintain the order

```
let j = "{\"b\": \"bar\", \"a\": \"foo\", \"1\": \"value\"}"
let js = JSON.parse(j)

// Get the keys and maintain the order
let myRegex = /\"([^"]+)":/g;
let keys = []
while ((m = myRegex.exec(j)) !== null) {
    keys.push(m[1])
}

// Transform each key to an object
let res = keys.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
     acc.push({
         [curr]: js[curr]
    });
    return acc
}, []);


console.log(res)
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

If I understand what you're trying to achieve for option 2. Here's what I came up with.

https://jsbin.com/pocisocoya/1/edit?js,console

```
let j = "{\"b\": \"bar\", \"a\": \"foo\"}"

let js = JSON.parse(j)

let res = Object.keys(js).reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    acc.push({
      [curr]: js[curr]
    });
    return acc
}, []);


console.log(res)
```

Basically get all the keys of the object, and then reduce it. What the reducer function convert each keys to an object

Comment: But once you do `JSON.parse` you have no guarantee of what the key sequence you get is. For example `'{"b": 1, "a": 1, "1": 3}'` can show in JS as `{1: 3, b: 1, a: 1}` so iterating through the keys, you'd get `1` -> `b` -> `a`, thus destroying the order. There you go - [example](https://jsbin.com/sadehax/edit?js,console). It does the re-order in Firefox, at the very least.

Comment: @vlaz yeah updated the answer to use regex to get the key while still maintaining the order

Comment: does not work for nested objects like `{"a": {"b": "c"}}`

Answer (score -1):

```
function jsonToMap(jsonStr) {
    return new Map(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
}
```

More details : http://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html

Comment: But you `JSON.parse()`d it, which lost the ordering.

Answer (score -2):

use for in loop

```
let map = new Map();
let jsonObj = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'}

for (let i in jsonObj){
map.set(i,jsonObj[i]);
}
```

btw, i saw the comment below and i think map is not ordered because you use key to achieve data in map, not the index.

Comment: @Logic, your answer demonstrates a way to populate a map out of already created object, while in the requirement the input is not already created object, but a JSON string in which an object is encoded.