# Is object changes immutably?

Tags: javascript, immutability

I'm trying to flatten and deep copy of an object.

Here's an example of how I try to do:

```js
const data = {
  firstObj: {
    data: 'Hi!',
    nestedArrayOfObject: [{
      name: 'hey',
      property: 'object'
    }],
  },
  secondObj: {
    name: 'second',
    nestedArray: []
  },
}

const object = {}
const keys = Object.keys(data)

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
  const items = Object.keys(data[keys[i]])

  for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j += 1) {
    object[items[j]] = data[keys[i]][items[j]]
  }
}

console.log(object)
```

As I understand, nested objects are being only linked to the new object, but not cloned.

How to do it correctly without additional libraries?

Comment: Are you trying to flatten the object or make a deep clone? What do you want the final object to look like?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm trying to make flatten and make deep copy.

Comment: If you want to flatten it, how will you deal with duplicate keys like `name`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I mean flatten only on two levels. The code in an example is doing it but by my knowledge, it not does it immutably to 3 level objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to make a deep clone

```js
const data = {
  firstObj: {
    data: 'Hi!',
    nestedArrayOfObject: [{
      name: 'hey',
      property: 'object'
    }],
  },
  secondObj: {
    name: 'second',
    nestedArray: []
  },
}

const object = {}
const keys = Object.keys(data)

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
  const items = Object.keys(data[keys[i]])

  for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j += 1) {
    object[items[j]] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[keys[i]][items[j]]))
  }
}

console.log(object)
```

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that way. Is it a performance friendly way?

Comment: You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662319/javascript-deep-copy-using-json) and also read the linked answer too

Comment: @chrisands does have limitations though...for example Date objects or functions

Answer (score 0):

```
let new_object = Object.assign({}, your_object);
```

Comment: Your answer came in lower quality posts. Please provide some explanation even though your code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const data = {
  firstObj: {
    data: 'Hi!',
    nestedArrayOfObject: [{
      name: 'hey',
      property: 'object'
    }],
  },
  secondObj: {
    name: 'second',
    nestedArray: []
  },
};
const object = Object.assign({}, data.firstObj, data.secondObj);

console.log(object);
```

Alternatively, use the spreading behaviour `...` introduced in ECMAScript 6:

```js
const data = {
  firstObj: {
    data: 'Hi!',
    nestedArrayOfObject: [{
      name: 'hey',
      property: 'object'
    }],
  },
  secondObj: {
    name: 'second',
    nestedArray: []
  },
};
const object = { ...data.firstObj, ...data.secondObj };

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Your `Object.assign()` targets the original object property

Comment: Whoops, my bad @AswinKumar.